# Error running executable file made using pyinstaller for my python project

Tags: python, pyinstaller, yolov8

I used pyinstaller to make an exe file for my project. When I run the exe file after its done I get the following FileNotFoundError:

```
Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandles exception:
[Errno 2] No such file or directory:
'C:\\Users\\p-IN-CHE7-ptsintern\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI96922\\ultralytics\\cfg\\default.yaml'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 391, in exec_module
  File "src\app\frontend\main_ui.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 391, in exec_module
  File "src\app\backend\oscilloscope_report_maker.py", line 15, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 391, in exec_module
  File "src\app\backend\yolov8\predict.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 391, in exec_module
  File "ultralytics\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 391, in exec_module
  File "ultralytics\models\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 391, in exec_module
  File "ultralytics\models\rtdetr\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 391, in exec_module
  File "ultralytics\models\rtdetr\model.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 391, in exec_module
  File "ultralytics\engine\model.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 391, in exec_module
  File "ultralytics\cfg\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 391, in exec_module
  File "ultralytics\utils\__init__.py", line 384, in <module>
  File "ultralytics\utils\__init__.py", line 354, in yaml_load
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\p-IN-CHE7-ptsintern\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI96922\\ultralytics\\cfg\\default.yaml'
```

I even tried updating my ultralytics package using pip before making the exe file. Still it returns this error.

It would be appreciated if someone would help me in this matter.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you include default.yaml in your installer?

Comment: Nope, all i did was type the command:
`pyinstaller main.py --onefile --windowed`

Comment: I am new to this, so can you help me fix this, if you know what is causing the issue?

Comment: You can submit issues here https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics , and they have a discord channel.

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I found a fix for this. So i went to the ultralytics package folder and I had to change a code from `__init.py__` under utils (`...\ultralytics\utils\__init__.py`).

I changed  the code on line 35 from:

`DEFAULT_CFG_PATH = ROOT / 'cfg/default.yaml'`

to

`DEFAULT_CFG_PATH = 'Absolute path to cfg/default.yaml'`

The cfg/default.yaml is under the ultralytics package folder itself.

I think it might be better to leave the DEFAULT_CFG_PATH empty, but I haven't tried it.

Comment: I used a better fix now:
cwd = os.getcwd()  # Gets path of working dir \n
DEFAULT_CFG_PATH = os.path.join(cwd, 'path to default.yaml from working dir')